# Promise.all doesn't seem to wait for everything to finish

Tags: javascript, ajax, promise

I want to execute an HTTP GET request that fetches some data, then create a few "subrequests" to execute based on that data, and then repeat this cycle: big request, then some small requests based on the data returned from the big one. However, I want the next iteration of the cycle to start only after **all** of the "subrequests" are done. My code so far looks like:

```
var end = w/e; // the amount of calls I want to make
(function recursiveCall(index) {
    $http.get('blahblahblah').then(function (response) { // "big" request
        var requests = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < whatever; i++) {
            requests[i] = (function(reqIndex) { // fill the array with a series of (different) requests
                return function() {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        // use reqIndex to create a different request
                        $http.get('blahblahblah' + reqIndex /* some modification based on i */).then(function (data) {
                            // callback
                        }, function (data) {
                            // error
                        });
                    }, 1000 * reqIndex); // need to pause between each req
                }
            })(i)
        }
        Promise.all(requests.map(function (req) { // execute the array of requests
            return req();
        })).then(function (data) { // I want this to happen only after *all* the requests are done
            // success!
            console.log('all sub-requests done!');
            if(index === end) {
                return 0;
            } else {
                recursiveCall(++index); // repeat with index + 1
            }
        }, function (data) {
            // error :(
            console.log("error");
        });
    }, function (response) {
        // error
    });
})(0);
```

However, the `then()` clause of `Promise.all()` seems to execute immediately after the "big" request returns with a 200; it doesn't wait for all the others to be executed. Why is this?

Comment: You're not filling the `requests` array with promises. You need to wrap the setTimeout with a promise, and resolve or reject it in the http callback method.

Comment: I did think about that; the fact that `setTimeout()` doesn't return a promise, but surely the thing inside (`$http.get()`) does? Does the `setTimeout()` wrapper stop `Promise.all()` from detecting it?

Comment: Yes. Create a promise before the setTimeout. Resolve or reject it in the http callback. Don't forget to return the promise immediatly (after setTimeout instruction)

Comment: How would I do that? Could you post a sample snippet as an answer?

Comment: Just use `return $timeout(…).then(function(){ return $http(…); })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a sample code to illustrate my comment :

```
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { 
    setTimeout(function(){

      // Then, in the http callback 
      resolve(); // or reject depending on your stuff...

    }, 1000); 
});
```

If you're using $q (in a AngularJS app), please refer to https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24q

Comment: Thank you! This helps a lot.

Comment: Quick thing: it doesn't seem like there's any difference between the native `Promise` and Angular's `$q`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Avoid the [promise constructor antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572) if you are doing more than `resolve()` inside the timeout. Also Angular does already feature a promisified version of `setTimeout`, so you should just use that.

Comment: $q is an AngularJS service wrapping promises for you, and falling back on a JavaScript implementation if your browser doesn't support native promises. IMO you should use $q for consistency and simplicity. FYI $q is based on https://github.com/kriskowal/q